# How to install 32-bit Ubuntu server alongside 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, server

I need to avoid the graphical user interface of Ubuntu 12.04.  Kindly advise if this can be achieved by installation of the Ubuntu-12.10-server along side the existing installation of Ubuntu 12.04 on my desk top. I would be most grateful for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Via along side installation you can boot into Ubuntu server or Desktop using grub2 boot menu!

Comment: Please explain more as how this is accomplished.

Comment: when we install Ubuntu along side pre-installed Ubuntu it will act as a another Ubuntu OS and we can boot in to that OS like dual boot with windows!

Comment: Supporting links found http://askubuntu.com/questions/234656/dual-boot-ubuntu-desktop-12-04-ubuntu-server-12-04-grub-mess-up

Comment: First of all, you don't need to install ubuntu server to learn and develop web apps. You can do this on your currently installed ubuntu desktop edition.

If you still want to install ubuntu server, you can do it without affecting the previous ubuntu desktop system. You can choose which one to boot (dual-booting) after that. The ubuntu server CD/DVD will guide you through the required steps to install the system.

It is very IMPORTANT to backup your files before starting the installation process to avoid data loss.
http://goo.gl/tHJPp

Comment: Thank you Sir for your advise, I will try to improve inputs.

Comment: @DanialJose You can always edit your answer, even after you post it, to include whatever information you like.